# Assigning a character array to struct variable | c

Tags: arrays, c, struct, char

I am trying to create a structure with the variable name being assigned to a chartacter array of a name. However, I get the error of "error: assignment to expression with array type" how do I solve this?

```
struct logrecord
{
        char name[100];
        char IPAddress[50];
};

struct logrecord readLog(char* logline)
{
// parse a character array that contains an line from the log
// and return a structure that contains the fileds of interest to us.
        struct logrecord studentinfo;

        printf("%s\n", logline);
        const char s[2] = ",";
        char * name;
        name = strtok(logline, s);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        studentinfo.name = name; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS HAPPENING

        printf("%s\n", studentinfo.name);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        FILE *data;
        data = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (data == NULL){
                printf("error opening CSV file");
                return 1;
        }
        char str[200];
        char * logline = fgets(str, 200, data );
        readLog(logline);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. To copy a string or a sub-string into an array use the function `strcpy` , `strncpy`, or `memcpy` as for example

```
#include <string.h>

//...
strcpy( studentinfo.name, name );
```